# Can't get the literal 'de' from dateFormat. Example: 8 de Enero de 2016

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to get a date with the following format using the jquery ui datepicker: d de MM de yy. Example: 8 de Enero de 2016

I've try with:
dateFormat: 'd \de MM \de yy'
dateFormat: 'd 'de' MM 'de' yy'
but it's not working as I expected, it displays 8 8e Enero 8e 2016 instead of 8 de Enero de 2016.
I have the code in the folling fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yewnu9jL/1/

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">

$(function(){
  $.datepicker.regional["es"] = {
        closeText: "Cerrar",
        prevText: "<Ant",
        nextText: "Sig>",
        currentText: "Hoy",
        monthNames: ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Ene","Feb","Mar","Abr", "May","Jun","Jul","Ago","Sep", "Oct","Nov","Dic"],
        dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
        dayNamesShort: ["Dom","Lun","Mar","Mié","Juv","Vie","Sáb"],
        dayNamesMin: ["Do","Lu","Ma","Mi","Ju","Vi","Sá"],
        weekHeader: "Sm",
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ""
    };
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd de MM de yy',
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelect: function() {
            $('#form-fecha').submit();
        }
    }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());    
});
```

How can I do it?

Comment: "it's not working" doesn't tell us what happens. Have you tried `dateFormat: "d 'de' MM 'de' yy"` to avoid the problems of the apostrophe terminating the string early?

Comment: It displays "8 8e Enero 8e 2016" instead of "8 de Enero de 2016"

Comment: Which one? You've mentioned two suggestions and I've made a third... you might also try `'d \\d\\e MM \\d\\e yy'`. (But looking at the docs, I'd expect the suggestion I made in my first comment to work.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried dateFormat: "d 'de' MM 'de' yy" and now it's working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to quote the text with single quotes... but to do that as simply as possible, you should use *double* quotes for the overall value:

```
dateFormat: "d 'de' MM 'de' yy"
```

Comment: @user3652062 This is the correct answer. Please mark it as accepted instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it with:

```
dateFormat: "d 'de' MM 'de' yy"
```